# How to LogOut from app with Facebook sdk 4 in android

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm updating an app that use facebook sdk, but i'm facing some problems, and official documentation is too poor.
On my app, user can log in with facebook or with a normal account (stored on my server), and this options are showed on app startup. Obviously user can also log out and log in with another account (facebook or not), and i have a problem with facebook logout. In fact i'm not able to logout user connected with facebook account.
As i've noticed after a lot of attempts, all changes about facebook status are tracked by AccessTokenTracker and ProfileTracker, that should be instantiated only once at startup.
I show (and explain) my code.
This is code of my login FragmentActivity that check if user was already logged in (with facebook or with dedicated account), and if yes, show next activity, else show fragment for choose access options:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                if (currentAccessToken != null) {
                    Log.i("LOGINACTIVITY", "token tracker, current token valid");
                    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                    //already logged with facebook, show next activity

                } else {
                    //check if current visible activity is logout activity
                    // that contains logout button
                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) LoginActivity.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

                    String top_activity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

                    if (top_activity.equals(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".LogoutActivity")) {
                        //launch new login activity
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                LoginActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

                    }

                }
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
```

Now it happen that, when i press logout button, accesstoken tracker execute else branch so show login options it's showed, but for some reason app automatically login again with facebook (it's invoked if branch of TokenTracker), so user is not able to logout from facebook.
What's wrong?

Comment: What does your LoginActivity do?

Comment: LoginActivity contains that code, and show login fragment (if user isn't logged in yet) or show next activity if user was already logged in

Comment: Can you post your full LoginActivity? I can't figure out what your code is trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the command: "LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();" you give me the life XD

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to stop access token tracker before logging out to avoid getting onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(...) called with a null currentAccessToken, which will cause - According to your code - to execute else clause.

```
accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

And BTW, you don't have to use startTracking() right after executing new AccessTokenTracker(), as AccessTokenTracker() implements startTracking()

**AccessTokenTracker.class**

```
public AccessTokenTracker() {
    Validate.sdkInitialized();
    this.receiver = new AccessTokenTracker.CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver();
    this.broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext());
    this.startTracking();
}
```

Comment: Is the line 'accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();' necessary for logout Facebook?? Only with the line 'LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();' my facebook session log out

Comment: It's necessary in his scenario / code flow, but it's not a must in all cases to successfully log out.

Comment: In my scenario I log into with Facebook and I take the user-name and image profile ... when I log out from my app I must put 'accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();'?? Thanks

Comment: No you don't ... If this is only what you do and you don't use accessTokenTracker.StartTracking() you don't have to call stopTracking()

Comment: I have followed a tutorial and I have put accessTokenTracker.StartTracking() in my registration method, but I do not know what it is and if it is necessary in my registration ...

Comment: If you are not using / executing any code within accessTokenTracker.startTracking() then don't use it, and if you use it, make sure to call .stopTracking() when user logs out. That's it.

Comment: @KryNaC If you found my answer helpful to you and solved your problem, it would be great to select it as an answer.